# Special expression for solution of heat equation

Tags: calculus, normal-distribution, heat-equation

Let us consider the heat equation on the quarter plane 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2},\quad t>0,\;x>0
\end{align*}
with boundary condition $u(0,t) = A$ and initial condition $u(x,0) = 0$.

Now we introduce $w(x,t) = u(x,t)-A$ where $A\in\mathbb{R}$, $u(x,t)$ is a solution to the heat equation and I've shown that $w(x,t)$ is also a solution to the heat equation. Also we have boundary and initial conditions
\begin{align*}
w(0,t)&=u(0,t)-A=A-A=0\\
w(x,0)&=u(x,0)-A=0-A=-A.
\end{align*}

By some formula from the book we have that
\begin{align*}
w(x,t)&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}\int_0^{\infty}w(s,0)\left(e^{-(x-s)^2/4t}-e^{-(x+s)^2/4t}\right)ds\\
&=\frac{-A}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}\int_0^{\infty}\left(e^{-(x-s)^2/4t}-e^{-(x+s)^2/4t}\right)ds.
\end{align*}

Furthermore, I've shown that
\begin{align*}
u(x,t)=A\left(1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}\int_0^{\infty}\left(e^{-(x+s)^2/4t}-e^{-(x-s)^2/4t}\right)ds\right).
\end{align*}
Now I want **to prove** that $u(x,t) = 2AN\left(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{2t}}\right)$.

Let's begin with noting that
\begin{align}\label{inte1}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-s^2}ds=\frac{1}{4}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-s^2}ds\overset{\text{def}}{=}\frac{\text{erf}(x)}{4}+C\quad(1)
\end{align}
and since $y=e^{-s^2}$ is symmetric in the $y$-axis, we also say
\begin{align}\label{inte2}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-s^2}ds=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{0}e^{-s^2}ds=\frac{\text{erf}(x)}{8}+C.
\end{align}
Let us choose $C=0$ for a moment. So far, so good, I hope.
Moreover, we note that in the integral equation (1) we can replace $s$ by $(x-s)$ or $(x+s)$ without the integral changing its value because whether $s$ ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, for exmaple, or $(x-s)$ ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ does not give another value to the integral; i.e.
\begin{align}\label{inte3}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-s^2}ds=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x-s)^2}ds=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x+s)^2}ds.
\end{align}
I do not know whether this equation above is right.
Now I try to go to the desired result and end up with question marks:
\begin{align*}
u(x,t)&=A\left(1+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}\int_0^{\infty}\left(e^{-(x+s)^2/4t}-e^{-(x-s)^2/4t}\right)ds\right)\\
&=A\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(x+s)^2/4t}ds+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(x-s)^2/4t}ds\right)\\
&=A\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(x+s)^2/4t}ds+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi t}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-(x+s)^2/4t}ds\right)\quad(??)\\
&=
\end{align*}

I have no idea how to turn that $1$ into some integral. Maybe it is true that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-s^2}ds=\frac{1}{2}?
\end{align*}
Does anyone have some suggestion?

Comment: Your last equation is true in any case, this is the Gaussian integral.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ ,

Then $X(x)T'(t)=X''(x)T(t)$

$\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=\dfrac{X''(x)}{X(x)}=-s^2$

$\begin{cases}\dfrac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=-s^2\\X''(x)+s^2X(x)=0\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}T(t)=c_3(s)e^{-ts^2}\\X(x)=\begin{cases}c_1(s)\sin xs+c_2(s)\cos xs&\text{when}~s\neq0\\c_1x+c_2&\text{when}~s=0\end{cases}\end{cases}$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-ts^2}\sin xs~ds+\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-ts^2}\cos xs~ds$

$u(0,t)=A$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_2(s)e^{-ts^2}~ds=A$

$C_2(s)=A\delta(s)$

$\therefore u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-ts^2}\sin xs~ds+\int_0^\infty A\delta(s)e^{-ts^2}\cos xs~ds$

$u(x,t)=\int_0^\infty C_1(s)e^{-ts^2}\sin xs~ds+A$

$u(x,0)=0$ :

$\int_0^\infty C_1(s)\sin xs~ds+A=0$

$\mathcal{F}_{s,s\to x}\{C_1(s)\}=-A$

$C_1(s)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}_{s,x\to s}\{-A\}=-\dfrac{2A}{\pi s}$ (according to http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/FourSin2.pdf)

$\therefore u(x,t)=A-\dfrac{2A}{\pi}\int_0^\infty\dfrac{e^{-ts^2}\sin xs}{s}~ds=A~\text{erfc}\left(\dfrac{x}{2\sqrt t}\right)$

Comment: Thanks for your input. First of all, I don't know what those three dots in front of $u(x,t)$ mean. Secondly, how does this show that $u(x,t)=2AN\left(\frac{-x}{\sqrt{2t}}\right)$?

Comment: @Algebear What is $N$?

Comment: Hmm, it's the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution. This was something I came across in an aplied analysis course but we didn't use any inverse Fourier transforms or whatsoever. So maybe there is a simpler solutions. I know about FT from PDE so I will look further into your answer.